# JPQL to query entity connected to another by @OneToMany

Tags: jpa, jpql

Has:

```
class Container {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    protected long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="container_id", nullable=false)
    protected Collection<Content> contents = new ArrayList<Content>();

}
```

and

```
class Content {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name="link_id")
    protected long linkId;

}
```

What JPQL query will get Content entities that are in Container with certain id and with certain linkId?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without making the association bidirectional, you could do:

```
SELECT c 
FROM Content c, Container container 
WHERE c MEMBER OF container.contents AND c.linkId = :linkId AND container.id = :containerId
```

But it would be easier to make the association bidirectional:

```
SELECT c from Content c 
WHERE c.container.id = :containerId AND c.linkId = :linkId
```

And the generated SQL looks better (and more efficient).